# get js array from 3rd party site programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, parsing

i want to have an array parsed from 3rd party site...

given a site:

(example:) https://videa.hu/player?f=8.1780672.2241728.0

if i type `videaPlayerController.contentConroller.context.xmlValues.video_sources` into console i get the sources, that's what i need...

The response comes from `VideaPlayerClasses.min.js` but as the name implies it's a minified js file... and i completly lost in the code trying to find what should i do...

any ideas?

Comment: You should go to https://videa.hu/developers and apply for access to their API

Comment: That was the first place i looked... none of their 3 api's proide the sources... for obvious reasons... the first `PlayerAPI` creates an instance of their player... basically the link i provided in an iframe... the second is the same, but with more information... like title and category... the third is for uploading/modifying and removing videos... ideally i would like to do a fetch in nodejs to get the array...

Answer (score 0):

There is the answer:
`https://videa.hu/videaplayer_get_xml.php?v=mmqkOXBnJVF4OHVJ&m=0`

`https://videa.hu/videaplayer_get_xml.php?v=`<video_id>`&m=0`

gives back everything about the video in xml...